# How do I prevent Apache2 from trying to execute a file as a script?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, permissions, scripting, cgi

So basically, I followed this guide [about iptraf monitoring and rrdtool](http://www.taedium.com/rrd-iptraf/) to the letter. I put it in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` as usual for cgi scripts. Then, when I visit it from a browser, the images it makes appears to be broken. I set the permissions to 777 temporarily for debugging purposes. I think Apache2 is trying to execute the png files as a script. How do I prevent that? Below are my configuration files. Thanks in advance!

Oh. And I'm running as root.

```
#tail /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Sun Mar 01 06:13:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-25-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-80-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:05 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-22-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-80-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-80-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-119-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.16      8.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-119-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-25-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:13:49 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-25-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-22-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-22-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-80-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-443-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.16      8.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-25-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-80-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-443-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-25-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-119-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.16      8.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:04 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-119-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:12 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] (8)Exec format error: exec of '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/tcp_services-22-6hr.png' failed, referer: http://192.168      .0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
[Sun Mar 01 06:14:12 2015] [error] [client 192.168.0.241] Premature end of script headers: tcp_services-22-6hr.png, referer: http://192.168.0.1/cgi-bin/tcp.cgi
```

This is the sites-enabled configuration.

```
#cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-exynis

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options +ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options +ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/tcpmon/>
                Options +ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my apache2.conf file. I added the **AddHandler** and **ScriptAlias** at the bottom.

```
#cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2-common/README.Debian.gz about
# Debian specific hints.    
# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf.d
#       |       `-- *
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.

# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
##

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
# It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
# client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
# browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
# where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
# unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
# incorrect  metadata.
#
DefaultType None


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see the comments above for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/

ServerName myserver
AddHandler cgi-script .rcgi .cgi

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
AddType image/png .png
AddType image/gif .gif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move your pictures out of `/usr/lib//cgi-bin/` folder and put them somewhere within `/var/www/` 
Update your paths accordingly.

Every time you trying to access any file within `cgi-bin` path it is expecting that content will be generated by executing that file.

Comment: Yup. That did it.

Comment: And setting +x to .png (with chmod 777) doesn't help on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

We serve one of our puny websites from a NAS-CIFS-share, so the unix-modes are all made up crock. Everything is mode-executable and nothing can be changed with `chmod`.

I found my problem was the `ScriptAlias` which told Apache to execute everything, even images. I thought going `<Directory ...> -ExecCGI...` for the `img`-sub-directory might be a good idea, but did not work.

I fixed my problem by moving the images out from under the bin-dir (now they are sisters) and adding a separate `Alias` (no Script!) and `<Directory...>`.